# How can I add multiple sources to an HTML5 audio tag, programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

A lot of examples demonstrate multiple source tags nested in the audio tag, as a method to overcome codec compatibility across different browsers. Something like this -

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

While with JavaScript, I'm also allowed to create an audio element like this -

```
var new_audio = document.createElement("audio");
```

Where I can set its source by the `.src` property - `new_audio.src="....";`

I failed to find how to add multiple sources in an audio element through JavaScript, something similar to source tags shown in the HTML snippet.

Do I manipulate the `new_audio` and add the `<source...` tags inside it, just like one would manipulate any other DOM element? I'm doing this right now and it works, which is -

```
new_audio.innerHTML = "<source src='audio/song.ogg' type='audio/ogg' />";
new_audio.play();
```

I wonder if there is a more appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Why add multiple files with JavaScript when you can just detect the types supported?  I would suggest instead detecting the best type then just setting the `src`.

```
var source= document.createElement('source');
if (audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg;')) {
    source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
    source.src= 'audio/song.mp3';
} else {
    source.type= 'audio/ogg';
    source.src= 'audio/song.ogg';
}
audio.appendChild(source);
```

Add as many checks as you have file types.

Comment: I'm letting the user push in a list of alternate formats inside class attribute itself, making a simple to use plugin to help them create audio hovers. So I would not be aware of what types did end users provide. Thanks for the canPlayType tip, would be useful.

Comment: Just something I noticed - you probably don't want to use the var keyword in your conditional.  You're creating a new new_audio variable, and not referencing the existing one.

Comment: @AndyWest Yeah, it was also missing a bracket - pretty bad code all round :)

Comment: No big deal... +1 since I found it useful anyway.

Comment: i tried doing <audio src="dropbox/link/ahc.mp3"> and it does work...any idea why?

Comment: This is a nice solution, but the post below better answers the original question.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the same DOM methods as with any other element:

```
var source= document.createElement('source');
source.type= 'audio/ogg';
source.src= 'audio/song.ogg';
audio.appendChild(source);
source= document.createElement('source');
source.type= 'audio/mpeg';
source.src= 'audio/song.mp3';
audio.appendChild(source);
```