# is it possible to define an mp3 and ogg file for jquery click sound?

Tags: jquery, click, mp3, html5-audio, ogg

i have this solution working in chrome:

[Play an audio file using jQuery when a button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/how-can-i-play-sound-in-jquery-when-click-a-button)

but firebug console says:

`HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource http://path/to/sound.mp3 failed.`

is there a way to define both an ogg and mp3 file in this script (assuming this would enable the sound to play in firefox):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://path.com/to/sound.mp3');
$('#play_it').click(function() {
audioElement.play();
});
});
</script>
```

thank you.

**update**

i tried just adding another reference to the file below the mp3 reference and it worked, not sure if this is the best solution though:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://path.com/to/sound.mp3');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'http://path.com/to/sound.ogg');
$('#play_it').click(function() {
audioElement.play();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add multiple sources to an HTML5 audio tag, programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053262/how-can-i-add-multiple-sources-to-an-html5-audio-tag-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `<source>` elements to the `<audio>` element in order to specify different sound formats

```
<audio>
    <source src="sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

jQuery:

```
var audioElement = $('audio');
var sourceElement = $('source');
sourceElement.attr('src', 'http://path.com/to/sound.mp3');
sourceElement.attr('type', 'audio/mpeg');
audioElement.append(sourceElement);
sourceElement = $('source');
sourceElement.attr('src', 'http://path.com/to/sound.ogg');
sourceElement.attr('type', 'audio/ogg');
audioElement.append(sourceElement);
```