# Can I set a (valid) empty src on an audio source tag?

Tags: html, audio

I'm setting up a website, and want to create an HTML5 audio player, but inject the source later on with JavaScript. I have prepared the following HTML:

```
<audio id=show>
    <source id=oggFile type=audio/ogg />
    <source id=mp3File type=audio/mpeg />
</audio>
```

Unfortunately, the W3C validator is panning my code, claiming `src` is a required attribute. Due to the way collateral code interacts with the player, I would strongly prefer not having this set to a valid audio file. I have for testing set the `src` to a dummy file...

```
<audio id=show>
    <source id=oggFile src=/audio/does-not-exist.ogg type=audio/ogg />
    <source id=mp3File src=/audio/does-not-exist.mp3 type=audio/mpeg />
</audio>
```

...but I'm not sure this is the best approach, and, in Firefox at least, it throws up warnings in the console.

Is there a way I can set an effectively-blank `src` attribute that still validates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create the source when needed. You can simply do that using JavaScript. In this way, your code is still valid.

Had to look for it but got it now. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053467/993547) that will help you with the code.

Comment: Would the `<audio>` tag not need a `src` attribute if it didn't contain `<source>` children? I suppose I could create the entire player dynamically, still.

Comment: I don't think so. But if you supply the source, you have to set src. So creating the control dynamically (or a part of it) should work.

Comment: Well, your excellent suggestion worked well, and I feel silly for not thinking of it before! Thanks! For reference to anyone stumbling here in future, since I didn't need multiple sources at that point, I just threw it to the `src` right on `<audio>` - which you were right, is not mandatory otherwise, so I could keep the `<audio>` element in from the beginning and just update its `src` value as needed, checking against `audio.canPlayType()`.