# Unable to add multiple audio formats to audio tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to have three file formats in one HTML 5 Audio Tag that plays for different browser.

```
function setAudioSource(source){
        var audioTag = document.getElementById("myAudio");
        console.log(source);
        audioTag.src = source + ".wav";
        audioTag.type = "audio/wav";
        console.log(source + ".wav");
        audioTag.src = source + ".mp3";
        audioTag.type = "audio/mp3";
        console.log( source + ".mp3");
        audioTag.src = source + ".aac";
        audioTag.type = "audio/aac";
        console.log(source + ".aac");
    }
```

The audio tag selects only the .aac file and not wav or mp3 files. It doesnt play wav or mp3 file  if .aac  audio is not present

Comment: As it stands your always going to end up with .aac as thats the last thing you set, see: [How can I add multiple sources to an HTML5 audio tag, programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053262/how-can-i-add-multiple-sources-to-an-html5-audio-tag-programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to create `<source>` node and append it. As of now, you're overwriting the same node.

```
var audioTag = document.getElementById("myAudio");
var wavSrc = document.createElement('source');
wavSrc.src = source + ".wav";
wavSrc.type = "audio/wav";
audioTag.appendChild(wavSrc);
```