# After refreshing page or sometime, html audio is not working, while base64 string is available inside src tag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using html audio element to play sound in **mvc 4** and `src` is dynamically filled.:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Parameter", new { @class = "form-horizontal col-md-12", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "messageid",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    }))
        {   <audio style="width:80%" id="56-audio" src="data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzAwAAAAAfdlRFTkMAAAATA..(base64 string)" preload="auto" controls="controls"></audio> 
}
```

when i refresh the page , its shows empty as below image while value is available in `src` tag.

[showing empty after page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmlV2.png)

so is there any solution to avoid showing empty `audio` element.

Comment: if you dynamically add source to audio then you have to follow http://jsfiddle.net/jm6ky/2/

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792163/change-audio-src-with-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: still not working. reason may be used audio element inside Ajax.BeginForm(){} object in rezor (.cshtml) view.

Comment: Please write `cshtml` `razor` code here also.

Comment: code edited with razor view code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cmr777/cdw9paox/#   ------ here  replace the src tag with base64 mp3 string and test from your side.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053262/how-can-i-add-multiple-sources-to-an-html5-audio-tag-programmatically/4053467#4053467

Comment: Is that the format of the audio source look like?

Comment: yes mp3 base64 string

Comment: @chirag if your source is dinamically filled, show us how it's done exactly